What key biological differences would make an anatomically near-human alien species significantly more likely to engage in space colonisation?
In my latest setting, there is a sapient alien species, the members of which are very human-like anatomically, being roughly as human as the elves, dwarfs, or orcs of classic high fantasy.
Unlike humans, though, there is something rooted in the biology of this species which makes them much more inclined to see the colonisation of other planets in their solar system as worthwhile. What could this be, though?
I am looking for one biological trait or a specific combination of biological traits which:

Would make a sapient species significantly more inclined than humans to see colonising other planets as worthwhile, even with similar technology to what humans have
Is compatible with anatomy which, at least externally, is as humanoid as the humanoid races of classic high fantasy
Is possible without psionics or magic

To summarise, then: What biological facts would, whilst being compatible with closely humanoid external anatomy and not invoking psionics or magic, make a sapient species significantly more highly inclined that humans to view colonising other planets as worthwhile at any given level of technology?
Edit:
Since some people do not seem to understand what I mean by this question, I will clarify: Biology influences psychology, and psychology influences how the same situation is responded to; I am looking for biological factors which would influence the psychology of a sapient species in such a way that members of said species would be more inclined to see the benefits of space colonisation as outweighing the technological difficulties and massive financial expenditures involved.

"view colonising other planets as worthwhile" sounds more a cultural aspect than a biological one. Two homo sapiens, with the same biology, can have opposite views whether going to a place X is worthwhile or not.

"view colonising other planets as worthwhile" also HIGHLY depends on circumstances. If we had a second planet in our system with a habitable atmosphere we would probably already have colonized it. Just imagine mars a little bit bigger with a breathable atmosphere and liquid water. That would lower the bar to colonize so much that we would probalby do it. Also the presence of certain ressources on this other planet could make it MUCH more worthwhile.

If my countries history is anything to go by - a Diet of Tea, Crumpets and portraits of the Queen....

The question is not answerable unless it is expanded to explain the methodology used to estimate the propensity for planetary colonization of plain old unmodified humans. Note that at current transportation costs planetary colonization is not economically feasible; this is why the question needs to explain how to estimate the propensity for planetary colonization, given that humanity has never yet been in a position to even consider it.

Every biological/psychology adaption that I can think of in favour, also creates new reasons against space colonization. Culture is likely to be the deciding factor here. Lets say they are actually good at long term planning; It could make the people invest more into schooling, research, and advancement. At the same time, it would make them unlikely to have an unsustainable amount of children, lowering the need to expand into new territory.  Blue people from avatar? Better at cooperating -and thus cooperative projects- through sharing emotions. Less innovation because of wars/rivalry.

Our sweet spot is you choosing the biological trait and we helping rationalize why it's driving people off the planet. Open-ended fishing-for-ideas questions don't work well here. How would you choose between the desire to get away from human stink to the desire for deep space due to overly light-sensitive eyes to a physiological desire for non-verbal relationships to any other inter-special relationship? We could list contenders all day.

Psychology is a non-issue.
Humans are already super colonizers.  If the possibility to live somewhere exists, someone is going to try to make it work.  The only reasons humans have not yet set up shop on other planets is because our technology does not make life even remotely sustainable on other worlds.  If there were another planet in our solar system that was as hot and dry as the sahara desert, or cold and dank as the antarctic, but otherwise agreeable to human biology, we'd already have millions of people lining up to go live on those worlds.  Heck the closest we have is Mars which we can promise a one-way trip that will probably end in a horrible death, and we are still seeing thousands of volunteers to do it; so, making your species less risk averse is not going to speed things up.  It could actually slow things down a lot.  We saw this in the late space race were Russia's early gains through bigger risks caused their space program to plateau when the more risk averse American program did better by spending more time on developing contingencies and perfecting their technologies before implementing them.
An even more risk averse species than humans might eventually do a better job than humans at reaching space colonization, but it will take them an even longer time to get there than humans.  So, instead of doing it with near future tech, they may wait another 1000s years until it is certainly safe before they even begin to try in earnest.  So, human psychology already seems pretty META when it comes to colonization.
A better solar system
Since humans are already such avid and well balanced explorers, the better thing to change than biology is the solar system itself.  Humans are cursed with a solar system lacking any other Earth-like worlds, but your alien civilization will inherently have a different set of opportunities than we do.  Maybe instead of a Venus, they have a smaller inner-goldilocks planet which loses its air faster allowing it to balance with its higher outgas rate, or they have a super-earth instead of Mars with a lower boil-off rate.  Either of these cases would make at least somewhat hospitable neighbor worlds far more likely to form.
Once you have a 2 planet civilization, you'll see a lot more space travel RnD happen over the new economic opportunities which will inherently accelerate the space race for other, less hospitable targets like asteroid mining.
Antifreeze proteins (AFPs)
As for biology itself, the smallest change with the biggest impact would be the addition of AFPs.  The biggest obstacle for space exploration for humans is that we can not survive cryostasis.  However, many kinds of plants, reptiles, and amphibians produce AFPs that allow them to freeze in a such a way as it does not cause cellular damage.  If humans had this feature, we could significantly reduce the the difficulty of space travel. We could simply freeze our crew for long trips so that they don't need any sort of living quarters, food, air, or any of our other complex biological needs for the long trip.  A capsule the size of the Apollo 11 lander could transport a small team of explorers to Mars almost as easily as it could to the moon.

Biological adaptations:
Something that might not first come to mind is body size. Like if you had a halfling-sized race that weighs 20 kg on average, you could also have smaller life-support systems, food, and water provisions. It is expensive to bring a rocket payload to space and every kilogram requires a ton of launch mass.
Another alternative I could think of is something akin to a human tun state, like a tardigrade. It could look really cool too, imagine them having the appearance of a mummified corpse only to come back to life after sufficient rehydration. You could have them be exposed to vacuum or go on year-long journies only to be brought back up later. I think they could look pretty human and still possess this trait.
Even if they don't have a Tun state, having the ability to hibernate to conserve resources would be very useful.
Psychological inclinations:
I think a general fearlessness/increased curiosity. A reduced risk aversion and a greater degree of openness. Perhaps even a reduced fear of death. Or at least a reduced fear of the unknown.
Aaaand I've accidentally created Kerbals.

I think there's two categories of biological adaptations that might make a species more likely to want to colonize its solar system.
First, there are reasons that they might be more compatible with an existing alien biology on another world than humans. Most of these are likely to be specific to a single other world in a solar system, though the work of getting their main colonization effort underway might lead them to colonize other worlds as stepping stones or test runs:

The species is alien in origin, and has a cultural memory of leaving (perhaps forced into exile, or fleeing a disaster). So the colonization effort is more "going home" for them, rather than finding a new place. This might not be too different from Tolkien's elves.
The species has a slightly different "alien" biology, which makes them more compatible with an alien planet known to have a similar native biology. This may wind up similar to #1, but without the cultural memory part, if the species' biological lineage actually originated from the other world, as some panspermia theories suggest may be common.
The species is native, but has a biological adaptation that makes them unusually fit as colonists on a specific other world. For instance, a sea-dwelling species might be more likely to favor colonizing a water world.

Second, there might be reasons that their biology favors them in the colonization or space travel process, rather than only at its end point. These don't push the species into space travel as much as they preferentially select for them as space colonists once space travel is possible.

The species might have a higher radiation tolerance than others. This would let them live longer in space, with less risks of developing cancer and other radiation-caused diseases. This might be more important if the local space environment is especially radiation intense (e.g. in the orbit of a gas giant, if the home world is a moon).
The species might have better acceleration (high and/or low) tolerance than others, which makes them better rocket crew. This might also let them comfortably settle higher or lower gravity worlds. But it is a bit harder to explain why such a predisposition would arise on the home planet, where everyone should be optimized for the same gravity.
The species might be biologically adapted to having a hibernation state that makes them very easy to transport through space, without consuming many resources on the way. This might be more relevant to inter-stellar colonization, where very long timeframes come into effect (e.g. flight times longer than regular human lifespans).


Colonies and Migrations
This is somewhat of an evopsych answer, and therefore, inherently bullshit, but: species, though humanoid in appearance, happens to have some sort of inherent, insect-like reproductive cycle, with a much more hive-like social structure, with strongly defined, instinctually grounded groups that dwell in a shared, mutually constructed and supported physical space. Even before they reached higher levels of intelligence, they were already building complex co-habitting structures.
And going along with this, they also have a deeply grounded 'swarm' instinct, triggered by overpopulation. There is a deep-laid itch in members of your species, when too tightly packed together, to form a large, cohesive group, split away from their home, and settle a new, distant colony.
This psychological underpinning means that when space exploration begins to be possible, it will unleash a yearning from within their very souls to depart from their overcrowded planet, and settle elsewhere.

Perhaps the aliens are biochemically more rugged than humans. With better and more extensive cellular repair mechanisms. This type of situation might have evolved if the alien's planet was subjected to higher levels of radiation than on Earth. In such a situation there would be a greater evolutionary pressure to have better cellular repair mechanisms to combat radiation.
Such aliens might see moving away from a planet with relatively high levels of radiation as beneficial. Their highly developed cellular repair mechanisms would no longer have to continually combat radiation damage and so might lead to a longer and healthier life, because their cells would be over built and more capable of dealing with the damage that does occur.
As an analogy if there were lots of fires in a town and a lot of fire stations and tenders to deal with it it, removing the source of most fires whilst retaining the same level of fire fighting ability would result in very little fire damage.
A longer life might also encourage space travel. Species with a long life would not find long space journeys represented a smaller proportion of their available years compared to humans.

Frame challenge: replace biology with engineering.
Space colonisation is going to need people to survive long, dull journeys in space with high radiation levels, high deceleration as they approach their target, and survival on an unfriendly planet.
Suppose you have molecular scale computing. This could be radiation hard, and light enough to send on laser-driven sails, and be capable of going into a dormant state with a very slow clock. This could have molecular-scale fabrication tools, so it can make building materials and tiny objects from the raw materials it finds. It can build micron-scale MEMS devices, and then macro scale tools, arms, and legs. It would be able to copy itself, and create intelligent swarms Something like that could be sent ahead of any colonising force to prepare a planet for habitation. It would build a transmitter, and report on its progress, perhaps via a chain of relay transmitters being sent from the home planet.
After a hundred years, they might have the site for a small colony. Changing the planet will probably take millions of years. This may also mean creating simple life-forms to help with the terraforming. But they can probably prepare a foothold in the time it takes your heavier and slower generation ship with the first colonists to arrive.
So far, this is just good design. Now ask: do your first wave of colonists get on the ship? Why would they go? Their intelligent swarms are their ambassadors. They are taking care of the planet. They do not mind travelling in space. They have learned to survive. In a real sense, they are the true children of the civilisation that sent them, but without the arbitrary limitations of biology. They may have made simple biology to help with terraforming. They could make more complex life. They might even encourage the evolution of other intelligent life, or copy the life-forms that designed them.
Choice: you can seal yourself and your family in a tube for three generations and fly out there to see for yourself, or you can sit at home on your comfortable planet and watch the News from Alpha Centuri. No contest IMHO.

Different social structure
Imagine a species with a social structure similar to elephants. A group of females living together with males living outside. This could lead to a situation where males are expected and want to do dangerous things just to become famous. This could make it easier and more socially acceptable to launch space missions with a high mortality rate.
Dependency on some rare elements.
Due to a quirk of biology, the aliens or the plants require high amounts of some rare elements for some enzymes. This might make asteroid mining far easier at profitable. Just sending some platinum-rich asteroid to evaporate over some country might earn you billions by increasing farming yields.
